# I can't test on a test database during my integration tests

Tags: spring, spring-boot, testing, junit, h2

I would like to do some integration tests. These tests would then use a h2 test database, which would always be deleted afterwards.
Here is my test:

```
@SpringBootTest()
public class PostePomponServiceIT{
    @Autowired
    private PostePomponService postePomponService;

    @Autowired
    private PostePomponRepository postePomponRepository;

    @Test
    public void addPostePompon_Ok() throws BadRequestException {
        PostePomponForm postePomponForm = new PostePomponForm();
        postePomponService.add(postePomponForm);
        assertEquals(1[![enter image description here][1]][1], postePomponRepository.findAll().size());

    }
}
```

and my main test class:

```
package com.MailleCoTech.SuiviProduction;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;

@SpringBootTest(classes = SuiviProductionApplication.class)
@PropertySource("application-test.properties")
class SuiviProductionApplicationTests {

    @Test
    void contextLoads() {
    }

}
```

My test-application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
```

and how my folder is structured:
[image]

My error is : com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

Answer (score 0):

Remove annotation `@SpringBootTest` from test case. You have `@DataJpaTest` which does everything `@SpringBootTest` + some extra stuff(you can check documentation for more details).

Comment: doesn't help :(

Comment: Are you getting same error or there is different error this time?  I just tried it on my side and I could reproduce and fix the issue.

Comment: It works ! but another error now.. How can I set up a h2 databse to just store my query and then get it and find the size ?

Comment: You can refer this article https://www.baeldung.com/spring-testing-separate-data-source

Comment: Is your property file being picked up? It should be inside src/test/resources and if it's name is application-test, then you need to use @ActiveProfile("test") on test class. You can upload minimum reproducible example to GitHub/GitLab. I can take a look.

Comment: It worked now, but not with the h2 database, only with my main db (on application properties...)

Comment: Testing on main db is bad idea. It should work with h2.

Comment: No, it's incrementing my main db :/

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you are using an empty @SpringBootTest.

but you also need to say the test which configuration classes you want to execute. I mean you say to the test "please execute a spring test", but you are not providing any spring application to it.

```
@SpringBootTest(classes={YourJavaClassWithStaticMain.class})
```

is what you want to do

Comment: It doens't work :/

Comment: what if you remove the @_RunWith annotation? The error says this:  found multiple declarations of @_BootstrapWith

Comment: same error :(((